# How to map an XML to Java objects by XPaths?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xpath

Given the XML example:

```
<fooRoot>
  <bar>
    <lol>LOLOLOLOL</lol>
  </bar>
  <noob>
    <boon>
      <thisIsIt></thisIsIt>
    </boon>
  </noob>
</fooRoot>
```

Which should be mapped to:

```
class MyFoo {
  String lol;
  String thisIsIt;
  Object somethingUnrelated;
}
```

Constraints:

- XML should not be transformed, it is provided as a parsed org.w3c.dom.Document object.
- Class does not and will not map 1:1 to the XML.
- I'm only interested to map specific paths of the XML to specific fields of the object.

My dream solution would look like:

```
@XmlMapped
class MyFoo {

  @XmlElement("/fooRoot/bar/lol")
  String lol;

  @XmlElement("/noob/boon/thisIsIt")
  String thisIsIt;

  @XmlIgnore
  Object somethingUnrelated;
}
```

Does anything likewise exists? What I've found either required a strict 1:1 mapping (e.g. JMX, JAXB) or manual iteration over all fields (e.g. SAX, Commons Digester.)

[JiBX binding definitions](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/index.html) come the nearest to what I'm lokking for. However, this tool is ment to marshall/unmarshall complete hierarchy of Java objects. I only would like to extract parts of an XML document into an existing Java bean at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the **[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** lead and a member of the **[JAXB 2 (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)** expert group.

You can do this with MOXy:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="fooRoot")
class MyFoo {

  @XmlPath("bar/lol/text()")
  String lol;

  @XmlElement("noob/boon/thisIsIt/text()")
  String thisIsIt;

  @XmlTransient
  Object somethingUnrelated;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). It's super easy. Hope it helps! I don't have time now for a full example :)

Comment: XStream looks nice, but also prefers a 1:1 mapping. It supports XSLT, which I would like to avoid: the original document is *huge*, and changes. XPath is more reliable in the long term and is perfect to access that 1% from the DOM I need.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be write a custom annotation which will take the XPath expression as input and do the bindings.